# SSL handshake issue for part of users

Tags: nginx, ssl, https, openssl, ssl-certificate-errors

I have a website that uses Nginx web server, It's work on both HTTP and HTTPS mode, but I'm wondering that HTTPS not working for some users while working for many users at the same time!
Also, **all users can load the site in HTTP mode without a problem, the problem is just in SSL handshake.**

Note: I gave the following command to my users and they gave me their outputs:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 -tlsextdebug
```

---

### Success output for many users:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 -tlsextdebug
CONNECTED(00000003)
TLS server extension "renegotiation info" (id=65281), len=1
0001 - <SPACES/NULS>
    TLS server extension "EC point formats" (id=11), len=4
0000 - 03 00 01 02                                       ....
TLS server extension "session ticket" (id=35), len=0
TLS server extension "extended master secret" (id=23), len=0
depth=2 C = US, ST = New Jersey, L = Jersey City, O = The USERTRUST Network, CN = USERTrust RSA Certification Authority
verify return:1
depth=1 C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = Sectigo Limited, CN = Sectigo RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
verify return:1
depth=0 OU = Domain Control Validated, OU = PositiveSSL, CN = example.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
..........
```

---

### Failed output for other users:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 -tlsextdebug
CONNECTED(00000003)
TLS server extension "renegotiation info" (id=65281), len=1
0001 - <SPACES/NULS>
TLS server extension "EC point formats" (id=11), len=4
0000 - 03 00 01 02                                       ....
TLS server extension "session ticket" (id=35), len=0
TLS server extension "extended master secret" (id=23), len=0
write:errno=104
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---

.......
```

Have you any idea that why this happens and how to resolve it?

Comment: Check your web server's error log.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I did check it and nothing found about this issue there.

Comment: For those clients where it fails - are they behind a firewall?

Comment: @SergeyNudnov Actually, I guess their ISP bans SSL traffic on some IP ranges. I want to change server IP address and I hope it will be resolved.

Comment: ISP bans SSL traffic?!! What country are they in?

Comment: @SergeyNudnov It seems that not all SSL traffic. just traffics on port 443 in some ranges of some datacenters. because I change SSL port to another one it's work normally.